# Python can't get the .get function to work

Tags: python, tkinter

Lurked around the forums but can't seem to get the get() function to works, it keeps returning that it is not defined. Can somebody point out what I did wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *
the_window = Tk()
def button_pressed ():
    content = entry.get()
    if (content == '1'):
        print 'lol'
    else:
        print 'boo'


entry = Entry(master=None, width = 8, bg='grey').grid(row=2, column = 2)

button = Button(master=None, height=1, width=6, text='Go!', command=button_pressed).grid(row=2, pady=5, column=3)

the_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `grid` method *returns* `None`. This assigns a `None` value to `entry`.

Instead, you want to assign that instance of `Entry` to `entry` and then modify the grid:

```
entry = Entry(master=None, width = 8, bg='grey')
entry.grid(row=2, column = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
entry = Entry(master=None, width = 8, bg='grey').grid(row=2, column = 2)
```

This will assign `entry` to the return value of the `.grid()` method, but `.grid()` does not return anything, so `entry` will be None.

You should instead write

```
entry = Entry(master=None, width=8, bg='grey')
entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
```

Do the same for all other widgets.